# Software update to Ventura 13.3.1 results in blank screen in system settings

Tags: software-update, software, ventura

When I go to update to latest Ventura 13.3.1, I click "Update Now" in the System Settings > Software Updates view. After clicking "I Agree" on the license agreement, the System Settings window just goes blank. I tried several times, and all that happens is when I close/reopen or navigate away/back to the Update section, it's back to displaying "Update Now".

Answer (score 2):

Just got it to work this morning. The solution was to scroll all the way through the license agreement before clicking "Agree". Then everything proceeded as normal (after a second agreement statement).